# How to debug bad access code 2 error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS app is crashing at a certain point in the application. I can reproduce the crash every time. I just cannot figure out why its crashing. I ran the profiler and checked for zombies - none found.

It crashes in two places first place is this method:

```
    -(void)toolBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    self.toolbar.clipsToBounds = YES;

    if (!hidden){

    self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
        self.toolBarHeightContraint.constant = 35;
        self.toolBarBottomContraint.constant = 0;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0
             usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
              initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                            options:0
                         animations:^{

                             [self.view layoutSubviews];

                         } completion:nil];
    }else
    {
    self.toolbar.hidden = YES;
        self.toolBarHeightContraint.constant = 1;
        self.toolBarBottomContraint.constant = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0
             usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
              initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                            options:0
                         animations:^{
                             //
                             [self.view layoutSubviews];

                         } completion:nil];


    }
}
```

At this link:

```
        self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
```

if I comment it out - the breakpoint stops at he next line when the app crashes again.

If I comment the method out completely, the app crashes in a  similar method, right below it which has this code:

```
    -(void)shouldMoveCollectionViewDown:(BOOL)move
{
    UIEdgeInsets insetDown = UIEdgeInsetsMake(41, 0, 0, 0);
    UIEdgeInsets insetUp = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (move){
        self.scrollbarView.hidden = NO;

        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setContentInset:insetDown];
    }else {
        self.scrollbarView.hidden = YES;
        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setContentInset:insetUp];
    }
}
```

at this line:

```
            self.scrollbarView.hidden = NO;
```

If I comment both methods out. No crashes. What else can I do to debug this crash?

**Edit**

This is what the console says. The reason I didn't add it earlier to this question is due to seeing this error a few times during the app runtime and it hasn't causes issue. I someone think it's related now though - however, I have no idea how to fix it.

> > Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
> >     this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
> >     don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
> >     constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
> >     NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
> >     to the documentation for the UIView property
> >     translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
> >         "",
> >         "",
> >         "",
> >         "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The
>   methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
>   listed in  may also be helpful.

Here is a screen shot of the error and the top part of the stack trace:

[image]

Comment: Could you add what is written in the console ? The exception that is raised ?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne I've added the console output.

Comment: That's not a bad access. If you're getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, you say you have a code of 2. What address did it report? Or are asking about the auto layout issue, which is probably a different issue?

Comment: @Rob what's the difference between EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a normal bad access? I am trying to reproduce the crash to get the exact error it shows me with the memory address. I'll update shortly.

Comment: @Rob updated the question with a screen shot - and here is what the address is: 0x16fcabfdB on thread 1

Comment: A "bad access" generally refers to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` which is generally an invalid use of a pointer (if a plausible memory address, often a result of referencing a deallocated object, if `0x0` it's an inappropriate use of `nil`). There are other, more obscure problems, but those are the common bad access situations. Frankly, I don't understand the distinction between "normal bad access" and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Thanks @Rob - Its 0x1 address. Which doesn't seem like a nil pointer? This code works a few times. Its only in certain cases where I am getting this crash.

Comment: Your stacktrace seems to indicate a infinite loop, where one of your methods called (maybe inside the delegate `scrollViewDidScroll`) leads to recursion. It then crashes to prevent your computer from freezing.

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll seems to be called every time my `ui`collectionView is reloaded. I believe that is normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes, but it gets called recursively : if it wasn't, it wouldn't stay in the stacktrace. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of this method, and continue the execution to see that you come back at the same place each time. Then, try to determine in which part of this delegate there could be some code that triggers it again.

Comment: You're right its getting called over and over again. I step through it and it gets called when I set the contentInset of the collectionView with a UIEdgeInset value.

Comment: @Bigood it seems removing that code has solved the issue. I'll do some more testing and I think I can do without the code actually. Can you make your  comment an answer and I'll mark as it has put me on the right track. Thanks :)

Comment: @Tander That was my guess! I made it an answer, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace seems to indicate a infinite loop, where one of your methods called (maybe inside the delegate `scrollViewDidScroll`) leads to recursion. It then crashes to prevent your computer from freezing.

To debug this:

- Put a breakpoint at the beginning of this method, and continue the execution to see that you come back at the same place each time,
- Then, try to determine in which part of this delegate there could be some code that triggers it again.

For example, setting some inset might invalidate the layout, redraw it and reposition the scroll at the previous location, leading to a unintentional trigger of the delegate.

*Note that the complain about constraints not being satisfied is involved by your code, but it's not what raise the exception. But it's still an error, and might lead to an unexpected layout.*